# Spring Webflow - error on spring-context.xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I have a project using Spring Webflow and I am getting an error on spring-context.xml file.

Error:

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'webflow:flow-executor'.   spring-context.xml  /GestaoAcademicaWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF  line 76 XML

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'webflow:flow-registry'.   spring-context.xml  /GestaoAcademicaWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF  line 78 XML

My attempts to fix the issue on lines 76 and 78 caused other errors to happen. Any guess of what is wrong on this file?

This is the spring-context.xml file.

```
   <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="br.com.devmedia.gestaoacademicaweb" />


    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" />

    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry">
        <webflow:flow-location
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/inserirDocente.xml" id="inserirDocente" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="docenteController"
        class="br.com.devmedia.gestaoacademicaweb.control.DocenteController" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `schemaLocation` URL with this newer one::

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd
```